# What time are the installer variables initialized?

Tags: install4j

Today we have a problem with the initialized `sys.installerDir` variable. I tried to use this variable to set the varfile location at the arguments-field in the installer screen (screenshot). It seems to be evaluated to a `null`-value and therefore the application start crashed because the file couldn't be found. The error logfile has the following entry:

`Could not read file [path-to-the-installer-executable]\null\plugin.config`

Now the question: may this be a bug or are the variables not initialized at this point?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No installer variables are initialized at that point.

To read a response file relative to the installation directory of a previous installation, use a "Load a response file" action in the "Startup" node of the installer, there you can use the `${installer:sys:installerDir}` variable.